# Run transactions - AppSync Aurora Serverless Resolver RDS

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using AppSync with aurora serverless resolvers. I would like to know if it possible to run transactions within the RDS resolvers.

I could run transactions using data api but in a lambda function resolver.

Comment: is there documentation somewhere by AWS that says transactions are not used by default or is it tested somewhere when using Aurora serverless resolver?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a stored procedure that you call from your AppSync resolver and have the transaction code inside.